# Local Host Owin Host

Tags: localhost, nancy

I am hosting a  simple nancyfx app in an owin self host.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (WebApp.Start<Startup1>("http://localhost:8002"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("START");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I can't connect over the LAN to this machine I have turned off firewall. Is it
possible to use localhost over  LAN and assuming a correct port forward config on my router is it possible over WAN?
At the moment i get:

```
Bad Request - Invalid Hostname
```

I was thinking that I am misunderstanding localhost.
Why do I get an exception when I use:

```
 using (WebApp.Start<Startup1>("http://192.168.1.121:8002")){ //my machines lan ip


Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the most helpful resource I have found for implementing a solution for an OWIN self hosted app in production.

https://github.com/danesparza/OWIN-WebAPI-Service#serving-more-than-just-localhost

The url the server is created at is changed to "http://+:9000/"

Hope this helps